# taking input and comparing same format as that of Date.current rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here is the form

```
 <div class="field form-group">
    <h6><%= form.label :start_date %></h6>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= form.date_field :start_date, class: "form-control form-input", required: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when start date printed it is printing in following format

```
2020-10-15 00:00:00 UTC
```

i want it in format of Date.current i.e 2020-10-15 so that i can compare it with Date.current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bad idea

Do not store formatted strings in the database as you're destroying your data modeling to solve a trivial formatting concern that should be solved in the application.

Its really as easy as:

```
Thing.start_date.stftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

There are also tons of other more elegant ways like helper methods and decorators.

Use the actual timestamp/date/time type columns that are suitable for your database and the domain.

If you store dates/times as strings/integers or something else silly you (and whatever poor sod has to maintain your monstrosity) will pay for it immensely when querying the data as you can't actually use it as a date without casting.

Like for example this:

```
Thing.where(start_date: to..from)
```

Turns into a monster:

```
# This code will only work on Postgres...
Thing.where("TO_DATE(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN ? AND ?", to, from)
```

Answer (score 0):

you if want to get date in particular format, then please use `strftime` method. Ref: [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

In your case use like this:

```
obj.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Happy Coding :-)